# How can I cause make -j to produce nice output?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a large project that is built using `make`.  Because of the size of the project and the way the dependencies are organized, there's a real benefit to building in parallel using `make -j`.  However, the output (that is, the logs and errors messages) that `make -j` produces is all mixed up, because all of the parallel tasks write to stdout at the same time.

How can I tell `make` to organize the output nicely?  Ideally, I'd like it to buffer the logs from each task separately, and then output then in order as they complete.  Is there any standard method of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `-O` or `--output-sync` command line options:

> **-O**[type], **--output-sync**[=type]
>
> > When running multiple jobs in parallel with -j, ensure the output  of  each  job  is  collected  together rather  than  interspersed with output from other jobs.  If type is not specified or is target the output from the entire recipe for each target is grouped together.  If type is line the output from each command line  within  a  recipe  is grouped together.  If type is recurse output from an entire recursive make is grouped together.  If type is none output synchronization is disabled.

The [online manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Parallel-Output) has more information.

(Note that you need [GNU Make 4.0](http://lwn.net/Articles/569832/) for this to work.)

Comment: Note you must be using GNU make 4.0 or above for `-O` support.  It's not available in GNU make 3.x.